# Exceptions on DBGrid editing

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I have implemented an editable DBGrid. If a field is not filled correctly an exception is thrown and a message is shown, for example:

```
'08:00::00' is not a valid time
```

How can I catch those exceptions so that I can show messages written by me instead of the automatically generated ones? I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: it is better for you to provide also the code that you already developed

Comment: this is not `DBGrid` exception. It is thrown by `DataSet` component in `Post()` method. What DataSet components do you use, ADO, BDE or something else?

Comment: I am using BDE. The DataSet component is of type TQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @teran pointed in his comment, the exception is raised by the `TDataSet` (or one of it's components) that is bind to the `TDBGrid`, or by the DB engine itself.

You can try to handle the `TDataSet.OnPostError` (see also `OnUpdateError` and `OnEditError`):

> *TDataSet.OnPostError:* Occurs when an application attempts to modify or insert a record and
>   an exception is raised. Write an OnPostError event handler to handle
>   exceptions that occur when an attempt to post a record fails.

Note that you could always use `Application.OnException` global event handler to catch any EDBxxx exceptions in your application.

---

**EDIT:** The `EConvertError` exception is raised **before** any actual data modifications, or any Post operation by the `TDateTimeField` field i.e.:

```
0045af91 +085 Project1.exe SysUtils       StrToDateTime <- EConvertError
004ab76a +042 Project1.exe Db             TDateTimeField.SetAsString
004a9827 +007 Project1.exe Db             TField.SetText
004a95d9 +029 Project1.exe Db             TField.SetEditText
004d6448 +014 Project1.exe DBGrids        TCustomDBGrid.UpdateData
004d087f +02b Project1.exe DBGrids        TGridDataLink.UpdateData
004d599a +01a Project1.exe DBGrids        TCustomDBGrid.MoveCol
```

`StrToDateTime` is throwing the exception inside `TDateTimeField.SetAsString`, not touching the data, and 
the `TDataSet.OnxxxError` event handlers will not be fired at all.

So your choices are (test the application in **release** mode):

1.Intercept and handle `EConvertError` via `Application.OnException`.
2.Use `TField.EditMask` to restrict user input to a valid time format e.g. `!90:00;1;_`  or use inplace [DateTimePicker editor inside your Grid](http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/l/aa121503a.htm). (and avoid catching this exception).
3.Override `TDateTimeField`: use persistent fields with your `TDataSet` and create an inter-poser class as such:

```
type
  TDateTimeField = class(Db.TDateTimeField)
  protected
    procedure SetAsString(const Value: string); override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ...

procedure TDateTimeField.SetAsString(const Value: string);
begin
  try
    inherited SetAsString(Value);
  except
    on E: EConvertError do
    begin
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
      Abort;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this solution (the OnUpdateError event handler) and it works OK with database errors but how can I handle convert errors? For example, when I fill the starthour field in the DBGrid and press Tab to go the next field I get the message: Project Text.exe raised exception class EConvertError with message ''7::' is not a valid time'.

Comment: Great thanks for the detailed explanation! I chose the third solution.

Answer (score 1):

If an exception is being raised then there should be two error messages being shown when run in the debugger. One of these will be caught by the debugger and the 2nd handled by the UI (when running your program as a user you will only see the 2nd).

The exception error message should have contain a string like

> Appname.exe raised exception EExceptionName with message XXX

You will need to take note of EExceptionName.

Around the block of code creating the exception you will need to write

```
...
try
   code that can cause the exception here  
except 
  on e: EExceptionName do
  begin
    ShowMessage('Your apps nicer error message here');
  end;
end;
```

note - if you don't make a call to exit; after handling an exception, your code will continue executing everything after your try..except block. Also, if there are many things that can cause the same error message in the same code block then you may not be able to write anything too specific. e.Message is a string that holds the message that is shown in the unhandled exception and may be useful to also present to the user.

Also try to move away from BDE - ADO is far better supported on modern systems.

Comment: seems to me OP does not use any code at all (`DataSource` in `AutoEdit` mode), because of that he dosn't know where in the code exception is thrown

Comment: In which case override the Post method of the dataset with `try inherited post; except on e: EExceptionName do`

Comment: I surrounded this code 'Query2.ApplyUpdates;' in a try...except block but the effect wasn't what I desired. In debugging mode the old two messages are shown and then the third message (my custom message that is in the except clause) is also shown. I want only my message to be shown.

Comment: @Rick77 it is normal for debugging. in release mode you will see only one message (wich is yours in `except`), try it.